# Using multiple ifelse

Tags: r

I have two vectors with equal length containing 0 and 1, but are not identical:

```
a <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1)
b <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

I want to create a new vector according to following if-rules, I tried

```
c <- ifelse((a==1 & b==1),1,0) | 
     ifelse((a==0 & b==0),0,1) | 
     ifelse((a==1 & b==0),0,1) | 
     ifelse((a==0 & b==1),0,1)
```

but was not working...
Does anyone has an idea how to realize this?

Comment: just use: c <- ifelse( (a & b),1,0)

Comment: What's your desired output? I guess you might just want `(a&b)+0L`.

Comment: More generally, if you actually do have multiple rules, you can consider `dplyr::case_when()` instead of multiple `ifelse` statements. Easier to read.

Comment: the less tricky version of nicola's comment would be `as.integer(a & b)`

Comment: Something like `ifelse((a==1 & b==1), 1, ifelse((a==1&b==0), 0, ifelse(...)))`. That is, you may be wanting to nest the secondary (and beyond) `ifelse` into either the "then" (2nd) or "else" (3rd) argument to the preceding `ifelse`. (I'm assuming your code is simplified for the purpose of this question ... if not, then docendo's comment is MUCH simpler.

Comment: thanks for your help! I realized it with the `case_when()` approach suggested by Z.Lin which also enabled to test various conditions easily.

Answer (score 4):

- Probably not best idea to mask the variable c
- If I understand correctly, it looks like you want c to be equal to 1 if and only if a and b are both equal to 1.  This could be solved with `c <- a*b`

Comment: yes, you´re right. c should be equal to 1 if and only if a and b are both equal to 1. But c should be 0 if a and b are both 0, and c should be 0 if a=1 and b=0, and c should be 0 if a=0 and b=1